# Onclick hide one div and show 2nd div.... in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-9

Working with an ancient device called Internet Explorer 9 (very long boring story to why I am using this)
But trying to get it so when a button is clicked it hides both div "one" and the button but shows div "two"
I can get it to work with Fire Fox but no clue to how to get IE9 to work all I get is a button that does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the native `onclick` event in your html, and call a function in your javascript for switching the visibility on both your divs.

Refer code:

```js
function switchVisible() {
  if (document.getElementById('div1')) {

    if (document.getElementById('div1').style.display == 'none') {
      document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#div2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Div 2</div>

<input id="Button1" type="button" value="Click" onclick="switchVisible();" />
```

Comment: It worked, and edited to get it to do exactly what I was after!
Thank you!